# rotating a 3d vector in java

Tags: java, android, math, vector, geometry

I got my device's magnetic XYZ values from the sensor manager.

however, those are the XYZ values of the device's point of view.

[image: device's point of view]

The problem is, i want those coordinates (the 3d vector of magnet values) rotated towards the north. I want to see the **same XYZ** values when i turn and hold the device however i want.

when using

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, accel, m);
SensorManager.getOrientation(R, v);
```

i get the XYZ of the orientation of the device in the vector v[].

now what do i need to do to rotate the original vector to fit the north?

this is the final result I'm looking for:

[image: as seen, i get the same xyz values for any orientation of the device]

as seen, i get the same xyz values for any orientation of the device

Edit:

I've tried adding this:

```
Location l=null;
GeomagneticField field = new GeomagneticField((float) l.getLatitude(),(float) l.getLongitude(),(float) l.getAltitude(),l.getTime());
```

and the data i get from field.getX() isnt valid (maybe because i use a null location...?).
any idea where i can find a sample code to help me out?

thanks,
Wops

Comment: If you want the same values independent of device orientation, what does reading the device orientation have to do with anything?

Comment: cause if i turn the device around, the XYZ values obviosly change as well. thats why i said i can use the orientation values -> but i dont know how :/

Comment: Perhaps you should edit or restate your question. I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Not clear. Magnetic field vector is pointing to North by definition. So, your X,Y,Z values are location of North relative to device. You should not rotate it to point to North, it is already pointing to it.

Comment: I believe (s)he's saying they want the same XYZ relative to magnetic north, such that the vector is always pointing in the same direction relative to Earth's magnetic field than relative to the device's orientation. (e.g. A vector that always points north). If that is the case you should look into Rotation Matrices.(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions)

Comment: Mike u got what i said, sry for my poor english, ill edit and add another photo. @Suzan u correct regarding the values i get, but the device take the magnetic values and put them in x,y,z dependet on the device's orientation

Comment: What do you want the resulting vector to *represent*?

Comment: the magnetic values at the current position regardless to the device orientation. Y will be the magnetic value pointing north.

Comment: XYZ is a vector, it is regardless (covariant) being a vector. It's components SHOULD change if the vector requires to be regardless. Any single fixed Y value will be incorrect. Meanwhile, you can calculate "length" with Sqrt[X^2+Y^2+Z^2], it also will be regardless being a scalar.

Comment: it seems like i cant explain myself.. :(
ill try again- i want the XYZ vector of the device when it is pointing to the north with lying on the table (azimute=0,pitch=0,roll=0).
and i want this XYZ to be printed on the screen ALWAYS regardless of the device orientation.

Comment: The "magnetic values" and the "XYZ vector of the device" have **nothing to do with each other**. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I've finally was able to turn the vector.

I used Mike's Advice and tried the rotation matrix thing..

the point is to take the current rotation matrix out of SensorManager , and to multiply it with your xyz vector of magnetic values (dependent on the device orientation).

[image]

A is the rotation matrix and the xyz is my magnetic values vector.

this is how u  write it in code

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, accel, m);
m[0]=Math.round(m[0]);//X
m[1]=Math.round(m[1]);//Y
m[2]=Math.round(m[2]);//Z
v[0]=Math.round((m[0]*R[0] )+(m[1]*R[1])+(m[2]*R[2]));
v[1]=Math.round((m[0]*R[3] )+(m[1]*R[4])+(m[2]*R[5]));
v[2]=Math.round((m[0]*R[6] )+(m[1]*R[7])+(m[2]*R[8]));
```

where 'm' is the values of the magnetic recieved from the sensor:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    switch(event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
             System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, m, 0, 3);
             break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
SensorManager.getOrientation(R, v);
```

which will give you the orientation of the device, use

```
GeomagneticField::getX();
GeomagneticField::getY();
GeomagneticField::getZ();
```

These will give you the components of the magnetic field, independent of the orientation of the device.

Comment: thanks for the reply. u describe exactly what i need. 

however, GeomagneticField is a class without the static function getX() (obviously), so i've tried to create an instance of it and call the getX() function, but i keep getting values which seems not right..

Comment: @Wops: **you** are right, **I** made a couple of typos which **I** will correct. **But** **I** will not chase this wild goose any farther.

Comment: thanks Beta, u can see i've already answered myself.
u can stop chasing gooses now.
btw- its still not working. '::' isnt java as far as i know. 
thanks again.